# Transistor series regulator heating

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, step-down

Hi friends i am trying step down converter using transistor.

Application:

- Micro controller power-supply = 3.3 volt
- Input battery supply range    = 10 - 13 volt
- So i use BD139 for stepping down from 13 to 5v and the using 3.3v regulator.

[image]

Circuit works fine and i connected my controller. But the problem is BD139 is heating up-to "45-49 degree". My controller consume only 50ma current. But i don't whether this heating is normal or abnormal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11-13V to 5.25V @ 50mA linearly regulated is 0.2875W to 0.3875W dissipated.

If ambient is 25C, then a temperature of 49C is a rise of 24C above ambient.

That works out to a junction to ambient thermal resistance of 126C/W. The BD139 has a listed thermal resistance of 100C/W without heatsinking. So that seems pretty close.

Comment: Ok thank-you for you reply friends. Now i gone step down from 50 to 12v, using mosfet. And i have a problem in that. I will post that as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

the answer of @DKNguyen is correct.
it is normal. so please attention :
Pout = 50ma*5.2v = 265 mw
Plost= 50ma * (13-5.2)V = 0.400

TO-220 thermal resistance = 100C/W

T = 25C + 0.4*100 = 65c

it is posible then we have to use heatsinking